# How can I keep my coconut milk from curdling when I am making dairy free gelatin panna cotta?

Tags: gelatin, coconut-milk

I make gelatin desserts and I’ve had very hit and miss results when using coconut milk in my desserts to make a dairy free panna cotta. There’s lots of advice for you to stop it from curdling when cooking but nothing really for the separating/curdling with gelling it. Thanks for any assistance.